# I've uninstalled one page checkout now my site is down magento 2.3.4

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, onepage-checkout

When I visit the site I get a 500 error and this in the error log.

```
[03-May-2020 16:00:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/magentos/public_html/vendor/composer/../iwd/opc/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/magentos/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
[03-May-2020 16:00:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/magentos/public_html/vendor/composer/../iwd/opc/registration.php' (include_path='/home/magentos/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/magentos/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Please help

Comment: i think install `composer install` your magento root

Comment: Absolutely amazing that worked followed by the other commands. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these set of commands.

```
php bin/magento module:disable IWD_Opc --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer remove iwd/opc
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This will not run from the command. It just skips down to the next line and adds the same error in the log again. `[magentos@server public_html]$ php bin/magento module:disable IWD_Opc --clear-static-content
[magentos@server public_html]$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
[magentos@server public_html]$`   

[magentos@server public_html]$ composer remove iwd/opc
iwd/opc is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Loading composer repositories with package information